# How to generate SSl Certificate (CRT), Private Key (KEY), Certificate Authority Bundle: (CABUNDLE) from domain.pfx file?

Tags: https

I have two files with me. One is **domain.pfx** and another one is **domain.cer**. To convert my website from **http** to **https** through cPanel, I need **Certificate (CRT)**, **Private Key (KEY)**, **Certificate Authority Bundle: (CABUNDLE)**. How to generate these files from the two files that I have?

Answer (score 1):

- PFX content: Your domain.pfx should contain everything(Certificate, private key, Ca-chain), you can check with: `openssl pkcs12 -info -in keyStore.p12`
- Key file: `openssl pkcs12 -in domain.pfx -nocerts -out domain.key`
- Certificate:`openssl pkcs12 -in domain.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out domain.crt`
- CA bundle:
  `openssl pkcs12 -in domain.pfx -cacerts -nokeys -out cabundle.pem`

Comment: Seb, while running the above command through CMD, it is saying
**"openssl:Error: 'openssl' is an invalid command"**.

Comment: @DurgaPrasadKundu, you can install it. Depending on your OS: `sudo apt-get install openssl` or download&install OpenSSL for [Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm). On Windows you should either execute the cmd from the folder where openssl.exe is, or add that folder to your PATH.

Comment: Yes, I did that and now it is saying "Enter Import Password:"... What password I have to provide here.

Comment: The password protecting your keystore: *domain.pfx*

Comment: Seb, but after the message "Enter Import Password" I can not type anything in cmd... Why?

Comment: After "Enter Import Password", just type the password and press enter.

Comment: can you plz say what should be used as the PEM pass phrase?

Comment: In which context? Key generation? Choose a password to protect your private key. *Don't forget to click on the check-mark on the left to accept the answer* ;)

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. One thing I want to add here is that, to extract the .pem file I have used **pkcs12 -in <cert.pfx> -out <cert.pem> -nodes** command. If any one can not extract the .pem file with the above mentioned command, then you can try this command too.